# Call failed after 702 milliseconds

Tags: karate

I see the error below when I run my first script.

> com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: http call failed after 702 milliseconds for URL: https://qa.myorg.intVersion.

Here is my feature file.

```
Feature: Test feature 
Scenario: Verify my service is up and running
Given url 'https://qa.myorg.int\Version'
When method get
Then status 200
```

Here is my Java file:

```
package examples
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate
@RunWith(Karate.class)
public class jenkinsTest {
}
```

I have waited manually for a long time in debug mode. Still, I see the error below and no HTML reports are loaded into the target folder. (I see ONLY Karate.log under target folder.)

> 11:36:23.751 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, http call failed after 271489 milliseconds for URL: https://qa.myorg.int/Version

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the [`configure`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure) documentation for SSL. Try this:

```
Feature: Test feature

Background:
* configure ssl = true

Scenario: Verify my service is up and running
Given url 'https://qa.myorg.int/Version'
When method get
Then status 200
```

Comment: I am still getting this error "http call failed after 2 milliseconds for url" even after triying with "* configure ssl = true"

Comment: @VirenderKamboj follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @VirenderKamboj Please try this:  * configure ssl = { trustAll: true }